# DAX expression for sub sums

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, dax

I have a following data set based on VSTS Task, User Story, Feature, Epic hierarchy

```
Id | Parent ID | Hours completed | Aggregated hours
1  |           |
2  | 1         | 
3  | 2         | 3
4  | 2         | 4
5  | 1         | 
6  | 5         | 2
7  | 5         | 5
```

I want to calculate for each row what is the aggreagated hours calculated as a sum of all its children. That means, I want to know how many hours have been spent per user story, per feature, per epic.

```
Id | Parent ID | Hours completed | Aggregated hours
1  |           |                 | 15 (3+4+2+6)
2  | 1         |                 | 7 (3+4)
3  | 2         | 3
4  | 2         | 4
5  | 1         |                 | 8 (2+6)
6  | 5         | 2
7  | 5         | 6
```

I tried to denormalize the hierachy, so I would have a hierarchy level as a column based on https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

```
Id | Parent ID | Level 1 | Level 2 | Hours completed | Aggregated hours
1  |           |         |         |                | 15 (3+4+2+6)
2  | 1         |   1     |         |                | 7 (3+4)
3  | 2         |   1     | 2       | 3
4  | 2         |   1     | 2       | 4
5  | 1         |   1     |         |                | 8 (2+6)
6  | 5         |   1     | 5       | 2
7  | 5         |   1     | 5       | 6
```

But this got me nowhere... Is there a way to achieve this in Power BI? Tried a SUMX but still far from the correct results

```
EstCumulativeHoursCompleted = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX('Work Items - Today', 'Work Items - Today'[Completed Work]),
        'Work Items - Today'[Parent Work Item Id] = EARLIER('Work Items - 
    Today'[Work Item Id])

)
```

Thanks for some hints!

P.S. Based on suggestion from Alexis, I mananaged to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect situation to use [Parent and Child functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/parent-and-child-functions-dax)!

You can define a pipe delimited path using the `PATH` function.

```
Path = PATH('Work Items'[Id], 'Work Items'[Parent ID])
```

Adding this to your starting table looks like this:

```
Id | Parent ID | Hours completed | Path
1  |           |                 | 1
2  | 1         |                 | 1|2
3  | 2         | 3               | 1|2|3
4  | 2         | 4               | 1|2|4
5  | 1         |                 | 1|5
6  | 5         | 2               | 1|5|6
7  | 5         | 6               | 1|5|7
```

Once you have this, you can sum up the hours for every path that contains the current `Id`.

```
Aggregated hours =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Work Items'[Hours completed] ),
    FILTER (
        'Work Items',
        PATHCONTAINS (
            'Work Items'[Path],             --Path column
            EARLIER ( 'Work Items'[Id] ) )
    )
)
```

You can also skip the intermediate `Path` column and just include the path definition within `PATHCONTAINS` instead of referencing that column.

```
Aggregated hours =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Work Items'[Hours completed] ),
    FILTER (
        'Work Items',
        PATHCONTAINS (
            PATH ( 'Work Items'[Id], 'Work Items'[Parent ID] ),  --Path Definition
            EARLIER ( 'Work Items'[Id] )
        )
    )
)
```

If you keep the `Path` column, your table should look like this.

```
Id | Parent ID | Hours completed | Path  | Aggregated hours
1  |           |                 | 1     | 15
2  | 1         |                 | 1|2   |  7
3  | 2         | 3               | 1|2|3 |  3
4  | 2         | 4               | 1|2|4 |  4
5  | 1         |                 | 1|5   |  8
6  | 5         | 2               | 1|5|6 |  2
7  | 5         | 6               | 1|5|7 |  6
```

If you don't want aggregates for the lowest levels, you can filter out rows where `PATHLENGTH` is equal to the maximal `PATHLENGTH`.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, tried above but it does not do the aggregation ... it copies hours completed only for the leafs . Shouldn't a sumX be used instead of sum?

Comment: Are you trying to write it as a measure? It did exactly what I showed for me as a calculated column. You'd need some tweaks to the formula if you want to use it as a measure.

Comment: Actually, no, I used it as a column ;/ I have added a screenshot to the original post

Comment: Hmm. It works for me. Maybe you have some other column affecting the row context. Try putting `ALL('Work Items`)` in the `FILTER` instead of just `'Work Items'`.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I think it works even though on the first sight it does not... I went with the results one by one and seems to be fine.  I will monitor the query further to confirm the results are correct